# To create a list manually is not equivalent to mget() when saving via write.xls()

Tags: r, list, object

**EDITED** (heavily):

Why does this work, and makes `write.xls` to save the data frames into separate worksheets...

```
vec1 = iris
vec2 = mtcars

library(dataframes2xls)
write.xls(c(vec1, vec2), file = "df.xls")
```

... but this does not? And how to circumvent the necessity to write manually the list of all the objects I want to have saved by `write.xls`?

```
dflist = mget( ls( pattern = "vec" ) )
write.xls(dflist, file = "df.xls")
Error in data.frame(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 150, 32
```

Comment: You may want to contact the maintainer since it behaves as expected (both with your earlier example and the edited version) when using a current version of R and dataframes2xls version 0.4.5 on a Mac. And _as_ _always_ you should provide the details of your R version, the version of packages and the OS that you are using.

Comment: Can you please clarify: Behaves as expected, meaning that the above described behavior is expected and I should request this as a new functionality, or that it is a bug?

Comment: I think I wrote the comment before I read the second part that throws an error. I agree the function is poorly documented.

Answer (score 2):

That function doesn't seem to accept named lists (which is odd).  I coerced your `mget` call to a data frame and it worked on my end. Maybe give that a shot

```
> write.xls(mget(ls(pattern = "vec")), "list1.xls")
# Error in get(s[i]) : object 'mget(ls(pattern="vec"' not found
> as.df <- as.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "vec")))
> write.xls(as.df, "list1.xls")
> list.files(pattern = "list")
# [1] "list1.xls"
```

Comment: Would be a solution, but only if such coercion can be done. If the 2 data frames do not coincide in the number of columns, this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that `list2` is a named list. They should behave in pretty much the exact same way. I'm not sure why `write.xls()` would treat them differently (what package is this from?). But if you don't want the names, you can do

```
unname(mget( ls( pattern = "vec" ) ))
```

Per your update, the way to reshape your data in the same way is to run

```
do.call(c, mget(ls(pattern="vec")))
```

However this is a very odd requirement indeed.

Comment: Oh no, my bad. The problem lies within write.xls {dataframes2xls}, and not at all in the difference of the two lists. I will update the question accordingly, sorry for this blunder.

Comment: @jakub I've updated with code based on your update. This is a very unusual function.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is throwing an error because write.xls is expecting an R object of class expression containing the names of objects rather than expecting the objects themselves. This is the code:

```
x.deparsed = (deparse(substitute(x)))
s = unlist(strsplit(x.deparsed, ",", fixed = TRUE))
 if (any(s == " ")) {
        s <- s[-which(s == " ")]
    }
    s = gsub("c\\(", "", s)
    s = gsub("\\)", "", s)
    s = gsub(" ", "", s)
```

So when given `c(vec1,vec2)` it converts to a character vector witha single element, splits the character into items based on commas and removes the enclosing `c(` and `)`. It's a rather clumsy way of processing an expression. It then does it's own `for(...){<other stuff> get(.)}`

The usual way to do this is to make `...` the first argument and then use `x <- list(...)`

Comment: ..and then calls `write.table`.  You're right, the source for this function doesn't quite seem like the right way to do it.